# php help needed, blogger api / xml warnings?

Tags: php, xml, blogger

I came across a script to display the last X amount of blog posts from my blogger account, however I'm getting this warning:

Warning: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated - argument passed by value; If you would like to pass it by reference, modify the declaration of xml_set_object(). If you would like to enable call-time pass-by-reference, you can set allow_call_time_pass_reference to true in your INI file. However, future versions may not support this any longer. in test.php on line 88

Here's the code:

```
<div id="latestentries">
  <ul id="entrieslist">
    <?php

    class RSSParser {

        var $insideitem = false;
        var $tag = "";
        var $title = "";
        var $pubDate = "";
        var $link = "";
        var $thr = "";
        var $counter = 1;

        function startElement($parser, $tagName, $attrs) {
            if ($this->insideitem) {
                $this->tag = $tagName;
            } elseif ($tagName == "ITEM") {
                $this->insideitem = true;

            }
        }

        function endElement($parser, $tagName) {
            if ($this->counter < 5) {
                if ($tagName == "ITEM") {
                    $title = htmlspecialchars(trim($this->title));
                        if (strlen($title) > 35) {
                            if ($this->thr > 0) {
                                $name = $title;
                                $name = $name . " "; 
                                $name = substr($name,0,31);
                                $title = $name . " ..."; 
                            }
                            if (strlen($title) > 45) {
                                if ($this->thr == 0) {
                                    $name2 = $title;
                                    $name2 = $name2 . " "; 
                                    $name2 = substr($name2,0,41);
                                    $title = $name2 . "..."; 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    $date = htmlspecialchars(trim($this->pubDate));
                    $pubDate = substr($date,0,str_length-20) . ".";
                    printf("<li class='entry'><a href='%s'><span class='entrydate'>%s</span><span>%s</span>",trim($this->link),$pubDate,$title);
                        if ($this->thr == 1) { printf("<span class='entrycomments'>(%s Comment)</span>",$this->thr); }
                        elseif ($this->thr > 1) { printf("<span class='entrycomments'>(%s Comments)</span>",$this->thr); }
                    echo "</a></li>";   
                    $counter = $this->counter;
                    $this->counter = $counter + 1;
                    $this->title = "";
                    $this->pubDate = "";
                    $this->link = "";
                    $this->thr = "";
                    $this->insideitem = false;
                }
            }
        }

        function characterData($parser, $data) {
            if ($this->insideitem) {
            switch ($this->tag) {
                case "TITLE":
                $this->title .= $data;
                $this->counter .= $counter;
                break;
                case "PUBDATE":
                $counter++;
                $this->pubDate .= $data;
                break;
                case "LINK":
                $counter++;
                $this->link .= $data;
                break;
                case "THR:TOTAL":
                $counter++;
                $this->thr .= $data;
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }

    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
    $rss_parser = new RSSParser();
    xml_set_object($xml_parser,&$rss_parser);
    xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startElement", "endElement");
    xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "characterData");
    $fp = fopen("rss.xml","r")
        or die("Error reading RSS data.");
    while ($data = fread($fp, 4096))
        xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))
            or die(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d", 
                xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($xml_parser)), 
                xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)));
    fclose($fp);
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);

    ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Could someone help me turn off the warning, or show me how to fix it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the "&" in $rss_parser:

```
xml_set_object($xml_parser,&$rss_parser);
```

Becomes:
    xml_set_object($xml_parser,$rss_parser);

Passing the object by reference should not be needed at all. It is automatic in this version of PHP.

Jacob

Comment: I'm sure lol Thank you for your help though, muchly appreciated! :)